# Remove spaces around passed argument via html/template

Tags: go

When i pass argument to onclick function i got spaces around that argument, why and  how remove them?

```
t, _ := template.New("").Parse(`<div onclick="test({{.}})">{{.}}</div>`)
t.Execute(os.Stdout, 1)
```

Result:

```
<div onclick="test( 1 )">1</div>
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e6-Se0-RQYr)

Edit:

Updated by Dave help, from template we can do something like this:

```
t, _ := template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "test": func(i interface{}) template.JS {
        switch i.(type) {
        case int:
            s := strconv.Itoa(i.(int))
            return template.JS(s)   
        // other types
        default:
            panic("bad type")
        }
    },
}).Parse(`<div onclick="test({{test .}})">{{.}}</div>`)
t.Execute(os.Stdout, 1)
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XdQnAXM60-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a result of Golang doing some things to ensure that malicious JS doesn't end up in your template.  If you specify that what you are passing in is safe for javascript, it will work fine.

> **type JS**
>
> Use of this type presents a security risk: the encapsulated content should come from a trusted source, as it will be included verbatim in the template output.

https://play.golang.org/p/TUOECg1YDtl

```
t.Execute(os.Stdout, template.JS("1"))
```

Result:

```
<div onclick="test(1)">1</div>
```